# Неправильное отображение документации Qt 4.8

Tags: qt, qtcreator, документация

Начиная с версии Qt Creator 4.2.1 и выше документация для Qt 4.8 выглядит так:
[image]

---

С документацией для Qt 5.8 все хорошо:
[image]

---

На более старой версии Qt Creator все хорошо с обеими документациями.

Кто-то сталкивался с этой проблемой? Может где-то можно скачать исправленные файлы документации? Или как-то собрать *.qch файлы через qhelpgenerator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Корень этой проблемы находится в `QTextEdit`. А именно в [баге](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-56848), который появился в версии Qt 5.7. Суть бага в том, что `QTextEdit` неправильно обрабатывает свойство `line-height`.

Есть два решения:

**Простое:** Ждать релиза Qt 5.10.
Там этот баг исправили. Соответственно, в версии Qt Creator, собранной с Qt 5.10 проблем никаких не будет.

---

**Сложное:** Пересобрать документацию вручную.

Под линуксом мне помогли следующие шаги:

1. Открываем файл `/usr/share/qt4/doc/html/style/offline.css`.
2. Заменяем все строки `line-height: <число>`; на `line-height: <число>em`.
3. Заходим в `/usr/share/qt4/doc/html/`.
4. Выполняем `sudo qhelpgenerator qt.qhp -o ../qt.qch`.
5. Перезапускаем Qt Creator.

Теперь в папке `/usr/share/qt4/doc/` появился файл [`qt.qch`](https://yadi.sk/d/6D5CNNDm3NPFGi), который Qt Creator подхватит автоматически. Для порядка можно переместить его в папку `qch`

Теоретически то же самое можно провернуть и под windows, но почему-то в Qt 4.8 для windows нет файла `qt.qhp` и я не знаю где его взять.

Результат :
[image: Успех!]